# Switch to the needed keyboard layout by pressing Ctrl+Shift+[1,2,3,4] on Debian?

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, xfce

**The point in short.**
I use *Debian, xfce4* and I need to use multiple keyboard layouts (to be exact, I have 4). I want to be able to quickly switch to the one I need without pressing Alt+Shift (or anything else) multiple times.

**What I need exactly.**
To switch to the needed layout just by pressing Ctrl+Shift+*[layout number]*. So, in my case it would be like this:

`Ctrl+Shift+1` - switch to Russian
`Ctrl+Shift+2` - switch to English
`Ctrl+Shift+3` - switch to German
`Ctrl+Shift+4` - switch to French

***A little notice***: I don't want to press some key combinations multiple times to get to the layout I need (sometimes it's a kind of trouble, you know), - so the question isn't about that - I can do this setting myself. The point is to get to the needed layout just by ***pressing*** its key combination ***only once***.

**What I've tried already.**
First, I installed `xfce4-xkb-plugin`, it was ok to get a language icon on the panel, but it didn't let me set shortcuts for all layouts separately. Anyway, now its setting `Manage layout` is set to `per application`, if it matters.
I tried command `setxkbmap ru` to switch to Russian, but what I got was a completely broken layout switcher, - I couldn't even switch back to English. Previously, I tried some other way, almost like this one (can't remember the command exactly), - layouts didn't break completely, only system shortcuts were broken. So I'm looking for a clean way to do this, without any drawbacks. Is there any?

I would appreciate any help with this.

---

**UPD.**

I've tried the following.

```sh
 setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc104 -layout ru,us,de,fr -variant ,,nodeadkeys,nodeadkeys -option grp:lalt_lshift_toggle -option grp_led:scroll
```

Generally, it seems to work fine, but some keyboard shortcuts still get lost (as I described above). The reason is probably that the same characters are bound to different keys in different layouts, and as for Russian, it uses cyrillic, so my custom shortcuts don't work in the Russian layout at all. Can't find a way around this so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody has the same problem in the future, I'm answering my own question. It's not perfect though. My solution is duck tape. Well, at least it's something. I ended up with the following bash script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cur_layout=`cat /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_value`;
target_layout=$1;

echo $cur_layout;
echo $target_layout;

if (( $cur_layout < $target_layout )); then
  switch_count=$(($target_layout-$cur_layout));
elif (( $cur_layout > $target_layout )); then
  switch_count=$((4-$cur_layout+$target_layout));
else
  switch_count=0;
fi;

echo $switch_count;

echo "$target_layout" > /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_value

for (( c=1; c<=$switch_count; c++ ))
do
   xdotool key Mode_switch
done;
```

Explaining what I wanted to do. I created 2 files: one is the script above, and the other is `/opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_value` as stated in that script, the latter stores the current layout value. Yes, I decided to store layout values in a file, and to reset it all on signin to the system. So there is a third file which resets it all, here it is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "2" > /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_value

setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc104 -layout ru -variant ,nodeadkeys,nodeadkeys, -option grp:lalt_lshift_toggle -option grp_led:scroll
sleep 1
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc104 -layout us,de,fr,ru -variant ,nodeadkeys,nodeadkeys, -option grp:lalt_lshift_toggle -option grp_led:scroll
```

**Detailed explanation**

I gave each language a sequence number, and it's used as a language identifier.
So for Russian I have `1`, for English `2`, for German `3`, for French `4`. And this value is saved in `/opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_value`.

On startup or signin the default value of `2` (i.e. English) is saved to that file, and `setxkbmap` sets a new keymap where English goes first. I couldn't get it to work without `sleep` though, so it's very duct tape. :) But just for the cases if anything went wrong it will do.

So the system started. Now I use the first script and call it when a keyboard shortcut is pressed. I set it all in the standard keyboard settings, nothing particular about it.

As a result, as I described in the question, I bound <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+[1,2,3,4]</kbd> to the main bash script (the first one). And, I have the following scheme:

- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+1</kbd> - `/bin/bash /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_switcher.sh 1`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+2</kbd> - `/bin/bash /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_switcher.sh 2`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+3</kbd> - `/bin/bash /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_switcher.sh 3`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+4</kbd> - `/bin/bash /opt/scripts/layout_switcher/layout_switcher.sh 4`

So, basically, what it does is call that bash script with one parameter passed to it, this parameter is the layout sequence number. The script takes it and calculates the offset based on the current and target layout sequence numbers, i.e. how many times a language switch must be emulated. :) As simple as that. I didn't come up with anything smarter. So if I was on German (3), and I want English (2), it calculates `4-3+2=3`, so the language switch must be emulated 3 times (in case with my layout precedence English is right before German). The target layout number is saved in the file.

All good, but this doesn't work for `Alt+Shift` switching, the current value doesn't get updated. But for me it's acceptable, because I'm not going to use `Alt+Shift` at all. And just in case anything goes wrong and I press `Alt+Shift` accidentally, I bound another shortcut to the reset script.

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+0</kbd> - `/bin/bash /opt/startup_scripts/layout_reset.sh`

which forces the reset to English if my languages got out of sync with the duck tape.

And one more thing I need to put up with: for all this to work I had to switch to the global language mode (from the application mode). So if I have English in one app, I'll have it everywhere else, till I switch to something else. No separate language for each application or window.

And, as you see, I use ***xdotool*** to emulate (i.e. to trigger) the layout switch. So, there is one more package to install, if you don't have it installed already.

So, it's a duck tape solution, but then again I'm not a sysadmin, I have only basic understanding. Maybe you know a better way, then please let me know.

**PS:** Yes, I've also read about `xkb-switch` solution, but it's not in the Debian repo (at least for now), and I can't inspect by myself, whether I can trust it or not. So, I decided not to take chances installing something I can neither understand nor verify.